# I have an issue converting a float variable into a string in C++

Tags: c++, variables, casting, c++17

I am not an expert when it comes to using C++ so I need a little help here. Consider the following code:

```
 float thresh = 3.0;
 string threshold = to_string(thresh);
 cout<<strlen(threshold)<<endl;
```

The terminal shows this error:

```
error: cannot convert ‘std::__cxx11::string {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}’ to 
‘const char*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘size_t strlen(const char*)’
cout<<strlen(threshold)<<endl;
```

What am I doing wrong here? I just want to convert 3.0 into a string. threshold contains a value like 3.00000 and the strlen() function gives this error. I would really appreciate if you could explain the reason behind this.

Comment: you did convert it to a string, but `strlen(threshold)` is just wrong. The length of the stirng is `threshold.size()`

Comment: You should read [to_string](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string): _"7,8) Converts a floating point value to a string with the same content as what std::sprintf(buf, "%f", value) would produce for sufficiently large buf."_ `to_string(thresh);` returns the string `"3.000000"`: https://wandbox.org/permlink/lrBeo7bKhgPrISMh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`strlen()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strlen.3.html) is for calculating length of C-style string.

To obtain the length of `std::string`, you should use the [`size()` or `length()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/size) member function.

```
cout<<threshold.length()<<endl;
```

In case you want to stick to use `strlen()`, you can use [`c_str()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) member function to obtain C-style string from `std::string`.

```
cout<<strlen(threshold.c_str())<<endl;
```

Comment: I tried     cout<<threshold.length()<<endl; but it displays 8. My issue isn't resolved yet :(

Comment: I tried all methods but it displays 8. The float 3.0 is converted into 3.0000000... How do I stop it from happening?

Comment: The length of the string "3.000000" is eight. It sounds like your question is not about string length but about how to format floating point numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You should use string stream instead.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    float thres = 3.0;
    ostringstream out;
    out.precision(1);
    out << fixed << thres;
    string threshold = out.str();
    cout << threshold.length() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

In case of to_string(float or double) 8 digits after decimal points are inserted in your resulting string.

Comment: Check the updated version. Output is 3 now.